# Multiplying subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

I want to find $AB$ where

\begin{gather}
A=\begin{bmatrix}  1 & 2 & 0 \\  0 & 5 & 2 \\  4& 7 &0 \end{bmatrix} \hspace{1.2em}, \hspace{1.2em} B=\text{span} \{ \begin{bmatrix}  1 \\  0 \\  0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}  0 \\  0 \\  1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}  0 \\  1 \\  0 \end{bmatrix}\} = \text{span} \{b_1,b_2,b_3\}
\end{gather}

Do I just multiply $A$ with each column vector of B such that my answer would be $\text{span} \{Ab_1,Ab_2,Ab_3\}$ ?

This might seem obvious, but I need to know whether my method is correct. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that you are not really "multiplying subspaces". You are looking for the image of a subspace under a linear transformation, in terms of a spanning set.

Answer (score 1):

An element $x\in\mathrm{span}\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$ is of the form $x=c_1b_1+c_2b_2+c_3b_3$ for some constants $c_1,c_2,c_3.$

By distributivity, $Ax=A(c_1b_1+c_2b_2+c_3b_3)=c_1(Ab_1)+c_2(Ab_2)+c_3(Ab_3)\in\mathrm{span}\{Ab_1,Ab_2,Ab_3\}$.

Similarly, any element of $\mathrm{span}\{Ab_1,Ab_2,Ab_3\}$ can be written as $A$ times an element of $\mathrm{span}\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$ by using the same coefficients. So you are correct.